# How to edit/update Joomla Article programmatically

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, edit-in-place

I am looking to edit / updated a joomla 2.5.8 article programmatically.

I know this can be done, but I do not yet know how; and I have found no help online..

Ideally i would be looking for a solution that would work on the client-side (Javascript / AJAX), to reduce server load.

I have thus far tried to POST (random HTML / text) to the *'jform[articletext]'* field in the ***<site_root>/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=<article_id>*** file without success

Does any one know how to do this?

Comment: Can you give a little more information about what information you are updating and how that information is changing? This can affect the best method to do this. Joomla has a great checkout system that you will have to work within to get a post like you tried to work, but if you all you are updating is the body there may be ways to avoid these checks.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from a PHP file, you just need to update the desired article from database.